# C# WCFサービスにアクセスした際のIIS上の動作方式について（プロセス構成など）

Tags: c#, wcf

WCFサービスをIIS上でホスティングした際に、クライアントからそのサービスにアクセスした際、
WCFサービスの動作モードみたいな設定もあるかもしれませんが、一般的に
どのようなプロセス、スレッド構成でWCFサービスが動作するのかご教示頂けないでしょうか？

IISはサーバ上で動作し、クライアント(Windows Forms画面）はPC上で動作します。

異なるプロセス上で同じWCFサービスが動作することがあるのか確認したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IIS自体のインスタンス数は`1`です。
- ですがリバースプロキシを構成することでIISのインスタンスを増やすことができます。
- 各IISが管理するワーカープロセスの数はWebガーデンを有効にしない限り通常`1`です。
- ワーカープロセスは数十分から数十時間に1度かならずリサイクルされます。リサイクルを開始すると既存のワーカープロセスでは新しいリクエストを受け付けませんが、受付済みのリクエストが完了するまでは新しいワーカープロセスと並行して動作します。(**Overlapped Recycling**)
- WCFサービス自体の動作は`ServiceBehaviorAttribute`の`ConcurrencyMode`および`InstanceContextMode`で制御します。既定値ではセッション別に別のインスタンスが作成され、各インスタンスはシングルスレッドで動作します。

> 異なるプロセス上で同じWCFサービスが動作することがあるのか確認したいです。

リサイクル中はプロセスが2個存在する可能性があります。

Comment: 「WCFサービスは、既定値ではセッション別に別のインスタンスが作成され、各インスタンスはシングルスレッドで動作します。」とありますが、これは通常は同じワーカープロセス上でインスタンスが生成されるという理解でよろしいでしょうか？（つまり、ワーカープロセスがリサイクルされない限り、static変数値やシングルトンインスタンスは保持される。）

Comment: はい。同一プロセスの同一`AppDomain`内で動作します。

Comment: @pgrhoさん　ありがとうございます。AppDomainの理解がまだできていないのですが、（別途勉強します。）
AppDomainとは例えば複数のWCFサービスプロジェクトA,Bを
WebSetupプロジェクトでサーバIIS上の仮想ディレクトリA,Bとして
分けてインストールした場合のA,Bの区切と理解してよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @mame アプリケーションドメインとは.NETアプリケーション特有のプロセス未満スレッド以上の実行スコープで、IISとは無関係です。通常は1プロセス1ドメインで動作しますので、気にしなくても良いです。

Comment: @pgrhoさん承知いたしました。